# I can't install iyzico bindings

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I run `composer require iyzico/iyzipay-php` and got this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - facade/ignition[2.5.0, ..., 2.17.7] require illuminate/support ^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires facade/ignition ^2.5 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition[2.5.0, ..., 2.17.7].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require iyzico/iyzipay-php:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require iyzico/iyzipay-php:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

My composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.5",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",

        "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5.0",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Then i tried running `composer require iyzico/iyzipay-php:^2.0` explicit version and still got an error.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1                                                                                                                                                      
    - Root composer.json requires iyzico/iyzipay-php 2.0, found iyzico/iyzipay-php[dev-gitlab-ci-test, dev-subscription-card-update, dev-master, dev-feyzullahdemir-patch-1, v1.0.1, ..., v1.0.12, v2.0.15, ..., v2.0.51] but it does not match the constraint.                                                                   
  Problem 2                                                                                                                                                      
    - facade/ignition[2.5.0, ..., 2.17.7] require illuminate/support ^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.                                                                                               
    - Root composer.json requires facade/ignition ^2.5 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition[2.5.0, ..., 2.17.7].                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                 
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I tried to update composer too but i got error again

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.3.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.3.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.4.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.4.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.5.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.5.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.6.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.7.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.8.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.8.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.9.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.10.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.10.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.11.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.12.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.12.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.12.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.13.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.14.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.14.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.15.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.16.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.17.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.18.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.19.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.20.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.21.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.21.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.21.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.21.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.21.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.21.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.21.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.22.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.22.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.23.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.24.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.25.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.25.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.26.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.26.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.27.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.28.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.29.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.30.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.30.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.31.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.32.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.33.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.34.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.35.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.35.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.36.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.36.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.36.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.36.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.36.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.37.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.38.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.39.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.40.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.40.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.41.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.42.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.42.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.42.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.43.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.44.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.45.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.45.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.46.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.47.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.48.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.49.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.50.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.50.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.50.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.51.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.52.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.52.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.52.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.52.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.52.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.52.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - facade/ignition[2.5.0, ..., 2.17.7] require illuminate/support ^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev]. 
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev, v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev], laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires facade/ignition ^2.5.0 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition[2.5.0, ..., 2.17.7].
```

Comment: Official Laravel 9 docs : "In addition, please replace facade/ignition with "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0" and pusher/pusher-php-server (if applicable) with "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^5.0" in your application's composer.json file."

Comment: Are you sure the error message is related to the package you try to install? It does not declare any dependencies